# rewrite url module in windows does not redirect

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have used `rewrite url module` but I am not able to redirect to the target page and
I am getting error as:

> The requested URL /old.html was not found on this server.

Here is my code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^old.html$ new.html [R]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is AllowOverride set to All in your httpd.conf? Like this:

```
   AllowOverride All
```

Also, your .htaccess should inlcude the L modifier for the last rule, and if you really want to redirect permanently, R=301:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^old.html$ /new.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `AllowOverride FileInfo` suffices.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the . in .html with a \

So its:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^old\.html$ new.html [R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try also setting the RewriteBase to / like so

```
RewriteBase /
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried this code for

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^old.html$ /new.html [R=301,L]
```

> error as The requested URL /old.html was not found on this server.

How to check the load module in apache server?